# Python iterating and dictionary

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to create a dictionary with keys that are every 3 items of the list such as..(a,b,c) then (b,c,d) then (c,d,e) and the value of each key is the direct next letter, so the value for (a,b,c) would be d and the value for (b,c,d) would be e. This is the code I have so far but the problem is when i becomes 2, the dict tries to append L(2+3) which result in an index error. Also..if num is = 4 instead of 3, then my code wouldn't work. Can I get some hints as to what I should do to fix these 2 problems. Thank you

```
L = ['a','b','c','d','e']
num = 3
for i in range(len(L)-2): 
      a_dict[tuple(L[i:i+num])].append(L[i+num])
```

Comment: Look at the [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: What would be the value for the key (c, d, e)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
num = 3
mydict = {tuple(letters[i:i+num]):letters[i+num] for i in range(len(letters)-num)}
```

Here `string.ascii_lowercase` is a string containing English alphabet in lowercase. You can treat it same way as a list (slicing, element selection).

Comment: Instead of slicing I would suggest you use `range(len(L) - 3)`  and I think OP don't know string and dict compression so bit explanations and demo are needed.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yep, fixed. I don't think there's much to explain really. It is a flat loop, and very similar to part of OP's code, I think it is quite transparent what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use "=" not ".append()" to add to dictionaries, i.e.

```
dictionary[key] = value
```

Also, you can use a modulus (%) to make sure that the list indexes do not get above the length of the list.

This slightly modified code works, including when num = 4 or num = 2 :

```
L = ['a','b','c','d','e']
num = 3
a_dict = {}
for i in range(len(L) - num): 
      a_dict[tuple(L[i:(i+num)%len(L)])] = (L[(i+num)%len(L)])
```

I hope that this is helpful for you.